# Linux Mint date not sync after reboot

Tags: linux-mint, date-time

I got a system date (time) problem since I upgrade using apt-get yesterday. The system date will set to a random date in the future (ie: 2030, 2027, etc. not the same everytime) after system reboot. I don't have the problem before.

I'm using Mint 17.1 XBuntu 64bit.

So, do anyone have the same problem? just me? and do anyone know what is happening, or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the battery backed hardware clock is working well. In a terminal, type

```
sudo hwclock
```

This will show the hardware clock. The system uses this clock to set the actual OS clock at boot time. If this clock also jumps around, there might be either a problem with the battery, or the OS is saving the wrong date at switching off. If the hardware clock is correct, then the updated OS is not reading it correctly at boot.

You could try to eliminate that last possibility by booting from a pendrive, live-cd, or, if installed, to windows, and checking the date there:

- Set the correct date in the OS
- Power down from the OS
- Boot with another OS
- Check the date there

EDIT (after determining hwclock doesn't work):
I found a couple on interesting links:

1) Gentoo: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7336102.html

```
Deactivate:
Device Drivers -> Real Time Clock

Activate:
Device Drivers -> Character Devices -> HPET High Precision Event Timer
Device Drivers -> Character Devices -> Enhanced Real Time Clock Support
```

2) Ubuntu: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1038099

Interesting: Seems Timidity might be causing this problem in this case.

3) Ubuntu (no solution published): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/325518

Comment: The output of sudo hwclock is: hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method. And when adding --debug option, it says that the Open of /dev/rtc failed: Device or resource busy.

Comment: @alsan: I've added a few comments to the previous answer, particularly about gentoo. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it suits you (use the 'V' left of the answer), so others can find it more easily!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to @jcoppens help, he give me the need to follow.

The `sudo hwclock` shows me it can't have any method to access the clock, and then notice me to use --debug option for more info.

The --debug option gives me that `Open of /dev/rtc failed: Device or resource busy`, and I then googling for that message.

And finally, I found this post: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=195046

All I need is to purge the **tlsdate** package, and reboot.

I don't know is this actually solve my problem (it need some time to prove), but now the hardware clock interface does have method to access and seems work just fine.